# purePdf problem?

Tags: purepdf

i am generating a pdf file with purePdf the problem is when i insert a table it leaves the space on the previous page of pdf and goes to next page even at least one row of its pdfptable can be accommodate on last page

how can i be able to remove this wide space from the page and my pdfptable  will be inserted so that there is no wide space remains.

help required

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way or doing this is divide the whole pdf in small independent components like paragraphs, chunks, images, and specially don't make big tables try to divide them in parts and small as possible so that each element can  take the required space. by doing so you are occupying the small wide spaces by small independent components so most of the wide spaces will be removed.